# how to jump to next tag while using Aptana Studio?

Tags: html, eclipse, aptana, shortcut

I'm using Aptana studio and I have a lot of `li` tags. It's a little annoying to go down and left each time you want to put something in-between the next tag. is there any shortcut that can jump the cursor to the next tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use TAB, for example with ZenCoding plugin I write:

ul>li*5

and it creates the list, then the cursor is positioned in the first

element and by pressing TAB or ALT+TAB I can go up and down in the list